# Why is my injectable angular service class not saving class variables as expected?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

1. in constructor, console.log ("My ID is:") prints out the correct ID generated by the server.
2. in getServerNotificationToken(), this.userID is returned as 'undefined' to the server, and prints as such.

WHY is my class not saving it's variables on the class? My understanding of ES6 javascript is that the 'this' keyword is bound to the class itself, regardless of which function it is being used in.

Thanks!

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GamestateService {
  public socket: any;
  public userID: number;

  constructor(private firebaseMessaging: FirebaseMessaging, public navCtrl:NavController) {
    this.socket = io('http://192.168.1.3:3001');
    this.socket.on('push-client-id', (data) => {
      this.userID = data.id;
      console.log("My ID is:", this.userID);
    })
    this.getServerNotificationToken();
  }

  getID():number {
    return this.userID;
  }

  getServerNotificationToken() {
    console.log("In firebase messaging...");
    this.firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) => {
      console.log("Token received: ", token);
      let tokenResponseObj = {
        token,
        userId: this.userID
      }
      console.log("My user id:", this.userID);
      console.log("tokenResponseObj.userId:", tokenResponseObj.userId);
      console.log("tokenResponseObj.token:", tokenResponseObj.token);
      this.socket.emit('token-received', tokenResponseObj);
    });
  }
}
```

expected: userID # assigned by server
result: undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only ES6 arrow functions are always bound to the class they are defined in, not normal functions, they are bound to the calling class.

You are calling getServerNotificationToken outside of the socket callback function so it is probably executing before the callback function has been executed, hence on userID being set yet. If you put the getServerNotificationToken call into the callback function you can be guaranteed that the userID is set before it is called.

```
this.socket.on('push-client-id', (data) => {
  this.userID = data.id;
  console.log("My ID is:", this.userID);
  this.getServerNotificationToken();
})
```

Comment: I couldn't see the forest for the trees. Appreciate it mate. It was indeed the fact that I was not putting the getServerNotificationToken() into the callback...